# HitTest and RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult programmatically in a window-less console application

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, visualtreehelper, system.windows.media

I need to perform the intersection of a line and a triangle mesh.

That operation would be very conveniently performed if I could use `VistualTreeHelper.HitTest` method, that would return a `RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult` structure.

The problem is: `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` requires a `Visual` and a `Point`, while I have only a `Visual3D` whose `Geometry` property is a `MeshGeometry3D` and a `Ray` custom class made from a `Point3D` (its origin) and a `Vector3D` (its direction).

So what I would like is:

```
Point3D intersection = GetIntersection(MeshGeometry3D mesh, Point3D rayOrigin, Vector3D rayD
```

irection);

But the framework offers me:

```
HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(model, point);
if (result is RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult hitTestResult)]
{
    Point3D intersection = result.PointHit;
}
```

From what I've read, usually the desired `Visual3D` would be put inside a `ViewPort3DVisual`, and the `Point` would be somehow transformed into a ray by the viewport transform, or something like that.

Since I don't have any Window so that I could have a ViewPort3D to put inside it, etc., I am clueless as to how I could use these helpers to get what I need.

Alternatively, if there is a library that would do that, I could gladly use it instead of WPF's 3D methods.

Answer (score 2):

The code to do this is a little more than will fit in a reply

https://github.com/charlierix/AsteroidMiner/tree/master/Src/HelperClassesWPF

Look in Math3D.cs

```
GetIntersection_Hull_Ray()
GetIntersection_Triangle_Ray()
```

Note that in GetIntersection_Plane_Line(), the third line is lineDir.Normalize().  This is a bug that I commented out, but haven't pushed up to github yet

The original source that this function was built off of is from:

```
Author: DigiBen DigiBen@GameTutorials.com
Program: PolygonCollision
Date: 7/11/01
```

Comment: Also, look in UtilityWPF.GetTrianglesFromMesh to turn the MeshGeometry3D into my triangle class that Math3D uses